# time complexity to find k elements in unsorted array using quick partition

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, quicksort

I know there is a method to find k smallest elements in unsorted array using quick sort idea. But it is said that the average time complexity is O(n), why?

For example, if in every turn we can get the pivot located at middle, 
for the 1st turn we need to partite n elements.
for the 2nd turn we need to partite n/2 elements(only left half part)
for the 3rd turn we need to partite n/4 elements
....
But the number of turns should be related to n, right? Why is the average time complexity O(n)?

Comment: This question is better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you tell us what you think it should be instead of O(n), and why, so we know where to correct you?